# Faking date/time of child process

Tags: unix, posix

On Unix systems, is there a way to fake the perceived date and time of a child process?

I.e., imagine:

```
$ date 
Fri Jun 28 10:50:35 CEST 2019

$ with_date 10/05/2019 date
Fri May 10 10:50:36 CEST 2019
```

How to implement the `with_date` command?

The typical use case would be the testing of date/time-related software, simulating various conditions.

Comment: You can override system calls related to date/time. For example, see [here](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/).

Comment: I think the way is to LD_PRELOAD the clock_gettime and related calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the library [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime). It uses a library preload mechanism to intercept system calls of the to-be-run programs. A use-case (from the manual) is:

> user@host> date
>   Tue Nov 23 12:01:05 CEST 2016
>
> user@host> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" date 
>   Mon Nov  8 12:01:12 CEST 2016
>
> user@host> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d"
>   FAKETIME_DONT_FAKE_MONOTONIC=1 
>   java -version 
>   java version "1.8.0_111" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14) Java HotSpot(TM)
>   64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: It's not intercepting system calls, but overriding functions from from the dynamically linked libc.so. That's why it doesn't work with statically linked executable or programs which dlopen() the libc.so explicitly.

Comment: Is there a technique that works on statically linked executables as well?

Comment: @gigabytes Since with Docker it does not work, a virtual machine is a possibility. I do not know anything simpler